# Support Vector Machine in Torch7

Tags: neural-network, svm, torch

I have based my model upon the following tutorial:

https://github.com/torch/tutorials/tree/master/2_supervised

For the last stage a neural network is used upon the features extracted from the CNN. I want to use a SVM in the final layer. How can I add that to my existing model ?

It has been shown in some papers that SVM seem to function better than neural network as the final layer in the CNN and therefore I wanted to try them out to increase the accuracy of the model. Also SVM's can be use for one class classification which neural networks lack.I need a one class classifier in the end and so the need for adding an SVM to th CNN.

Kindly help

Comment: This isn't an official answer, but have you considered rolling your own SVM module? All you'd need to do is write your own forwards and backwards message functions... The hardest part, conceptually, will be taking derivatives of the response function...

Comment: Also, I'm sure you saw this, but there's a google group question dedicated to this problem (kinda of): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/torch7/bEDxJgaDlj8

Comment: please review my edit -- I may have just disqualified it fro being "acceptable", sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Edit:*** My old answer was complete rubbish since you [cannot code a (linear) SVM as a complete module](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158712/train-an-svm-via-back-propagation/158721#158721). Instead, you can think of an SVM as

> a 1-layer NN with linear activation on the output node and trained via hinge loss

(see accepted answer's comments.)

This means that in Torch, you can mock up a (linear) SVM with something like

```
linearSVM = nn.Sequential()
linearSVM:add(nn.Linear(ninputs, 1))
criterion = nn.MarginCriterion()
```

see the following question in the [Torch7 google code mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/torch7/SVM/torch7/2YKxbyVkAs0/cn_tqsyxG8cJ)...

Comment: Thanx a lot !! I dug up a little and found that one way to add an SVM upon the CNN is to make it completely independent of the CNN. Train the CNN as you'd normally do and the once trained, train an SVM upon the training set with the features extracted from CNN. This avoids the routine of updating the weights and calculating the gradients 'manually'. But this still leaves the aspect of having a one class SVM unanswered- as I'd still have to sample negative examples for the CNN. The other way is definitely the one you suggested, but it sure does seem a bit too involved for me to hande !

Comment: I was going to try and extend my code example to fully define the `linearSVM` module, but I realized that this approach might be fundamentally flawed: I don't think you can train an SVM using back-prop since forward message has a derivative that is constantly 0 for all input and parameters...